# jquery .bind('click.select') is not working in mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

So I have this code that whenever a page is onLoad, the user is not able to click any of the links unless it has finished loading the page in a specific region.

```
// note: this events are for the specific li tags of this.ui.liLink
'events' : {
    'click @ui.catalogTab'      : 'showCatalogsTabView',
    'click @ui.transcriptTab'   : 'showTranscriptsTabView',
    'click @ui.facilitationTab' : 'showFacilitationTabView'
},
'ui' : {
    'liLink' : '.catalog-menu > ul > li'
},

'enableTabClick' : function () {
    this.ui.liLink.removeClass( 'disabled' );
    this.ui.liLink.unbind( 'click.select' );
},

'disableTabClick' : function () {
    this.ui.liLink.addClass( 'disabled' );
    this.ui.liLink.bind( 'click.select', false );
}
```

this is working perfectly on desktop but when I use it on mobile devices, .bind() is not working and does not disable the event listener for click events. How do I do it on mobile?

Comment: where's the code that shows why `bind` does? because if you didn't redefine it, it's a global, spec-defined function that you use to generate a new function with the `this` context bound to whatever you passed in (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: This is `jQuery().bind()`, not the `bind` you're thinking of.

Comment: Sorry, spoke too soon. Apparently this is backbone's `bind`. Still not the bind you're thinking of.

Comment: FWIW both jQuery and backbone implements a method called `bind` to mean `attachEvent`

Comment: Is there something am I missing when calling jQuery().bind() on mobile?

Comment: When you say "disable the event listener", what event listener do you mean? Do you have another handler bound to the same `li` elements? Using jquery or otherwise? Or is it on elements inside the `li`? Or do you just have `a` elements in the `li`s? You may need to call `bind()` on the inner elements (if they exist) instead of the `li`. Adding `onclick=""` (literally that, with empty `""`) to the `li` might also help, as might setting `cursor:pointer` in the CSS to let the browser know it's a clickable element. Finally, what mobile browsers/OSes have you tested on?

Comment: @slebetman out of curiosity, why do you say it's backbone rather than jquery? Does backbone support the `.bind(x,false)` shorthand?

Comment: yes. I have updated my problem with the events @CupawnTae so when I call disableTabClick it is expected that they won't call the events of each specific li when clicked. This is working in desktop, but it does not work in mobile.

Comment: Inside my li elements also has  a  elements, I have also tried binding in the inner element but still has not worked out for me on mobile @CupawnTae

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally solved my problem. In mobile, the event you have to listen for is touchstart. So I added it to my current code.

```
    'enableTabClick' : function () {
        this.ui.liLink.removeClass( 'disabled' );
        this.ui.liLink.unbind( 'click.select touchstart' );
    },

    'disableTabClick' : function () {
        this.ui.liLink.addClass( 'disabled' );
        this.ui.liLink.bind( 'click.select touchstart', false );
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because in mobile devices there are not such events "click". Try mobile events - "tap" or "drag" for example. I think that problem in it.

Comment: I have tried both of these solutions days ago but still does not solve it for me in mobile.